# Python pass password as a argument and does not echo password

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments, subprocess

I am passing password as argument to run in remote machine. Problem  is when script is failed, it displaying password on terminal.

Which is security issue.

Python script:

```
 username = "testuser"
 password = getpass.getpass("password:")
 ['ssh', '-t', '1.1.1.1', 'python -u pull_details.py username password --get_name']
```

Problem is Password is displaying when script is failed like below

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 575, in check_output
  raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ssh', '-t', '1.1.1.1', 'python -u pull_details.py testuser testpassword --get_name']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Is there way I can restrict displaying password?

Comment: Read about [Set up SSH using certificate authentication](http://www.askmeaboutlinux.com/?p=1291)

Comment: Password is for remote devices. This  devices  does not able to configure ssh key like in network devices

Comment: Ask the admin to do so.

Comment: They said its not possible

Comment: It seems you are able to login to a server console. Check the output of `cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep Authentication` if ssh is allready enabeld to allow certs.

Comment: Perhaps you can try to usie `paramiko` to handle your ssh session, instead of using a `subprocess`?

Comment: No Paramiko not used, i try this